# Suggestion on Robotic Localization

Tags: algorithm, localization, robotics

I am programming an Automatic Guided vehicle (AGV), like the one being used in Amazon ware-house. Please have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_guided_vehicle).

Problem:

So I am facing problem in AGV localization. I can not use expensive sensors or camera for localization. Now have a look at the image below.
[image]

If the red circle is considered to be the AGV and the thick line is the track on which it moves. When the AGV starts up, for localization I am thinking to move the it to one end (reference location) of the track. And initializing location as (0,0) with a super cheap [Hall-Effect sensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect_sensor).
Is there any other way I can do it ? The track has been mapped onto a grid for path planning.

Comment: No camera and no "expensive" sensors.... what sensors do you have? Odometry and bump? How good of a bump sensor? Jason O'Kane has a variety of good papers on the topic: [Localization w/ limited sensing](http://scholarcommons.sc.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1000&context=csce_facpub) [Almost sensorless localization](http://msl.cs.uiuc.edu/~jokane/papers/ms.pdf) [And more](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=ETFTMZMAAAAJ&hl=en&oi=sra) Google Scholar is your friend.

Comment: Thank you so much. I only have encoders with the wheel(encoder outputs the number of rotation wheel has made) to do some dead reckoning for position calculation. But that's only when the robot has been initialized with a reference location. My issue is with initializing the robot with some reference location. I have also looked into some papers which speaks about "marker" and "landmark" based robotic initialization, that's out of scope for my work.  But thanks again, I will go through the papers.

Answer (score 2):

An optical sensor would be better because it has longer range and is less sensitive to differences in distance.

I would put reflectors at key points along the track. The robot would have a small IR transmitter and detector right next to it. If the beam is reflected, then the robot knows it is over a reflector.

Comment: Thank you so so much for the input. I have a blunt question, can the detector, uniquely identify the reflector? Cause I can use these reflectors as my landmarks and make the robot move based on the strength of the reflected IR light.